# Understanding DNS in wireshark output

Tags: dns, wireshark

I used wireshark to collect data from some sites, and then used tcpdump to get it as a text file.  For the project I'm working on, I want to count how many DNS resolutions are involved in accessing a particular website, and what the nature of the DNS responses was.  The problem is I don't really understand the output from wireshark or how to interpret it to find what I'm looking for.  For instance, here is a line:

> 21:08:05.454852 IP 10.0.0.2.57512 > ord08s09-in-f21.1e100.net.https:
>   Flags [.], seq 1:1419, ack 55, win 65535, options [nop,nop,TS val
>   1348891674 ecr 2473250009], length 1418

What do the different parts of this mean, and what will the data I'm looking for look like?  I'm worried I might be using Wireshark incorrectly without knowing it.

Answer (score 4):

> I used wireshark to collect data from some sites, and then used tcpdump to get it as a text file.

Most people who use both tools use them for the opposite purposes. :-)  I.e., they use tcpdump to capture traffic into a file and then read the file with Wireshark.  If you're only using Wireshark to *capture* traffic, that's probably overkill - you can do the same thing with dumpcap or possibly even tcpdump.

The output you're showing is text output, so, if you "used tcpdump to get it as a text file", it's output from *tcpdump*, not from *Wireshark*; text output from Wireshark would look different.  If you "used wireshark to collect data from some sites, and then used tcpdump to get it as a text file", the output from Wireshark is either a [pcap file](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-savefile.5.html) or a [pcap-ng file](http://www.winpcap.org/ntar/draft/PCAP-DumpFileFormat.html), which is a binary file, and is completely uninterpreted raw data.  The interpretation of the data in your example is being done by tcpdump, not Wireshark.

What the output is saying is:

"21:08:05.454852": the packet arrived at 21:08:05 and a fraction of a second, local time.

"IP": the packet is an IPv4 packet.

"10.0.0.2.57512 > ord08s09-in-f21.1e100.net.https": the packet is from IP address 10.0.0.2, port 57512, to the IP address whose for which the host name is "ord08s09-in-f21.1e100.net", and the port for "https", which is port 443.

See the tcpdump man page, and a description of TCP, for details on the rest of the line.

The key point here is that this is *NOT* DNS traffic!  It's probably "HTTP-over-SSL", or "https", traffic.

In tcpdump, DNS traffic would look like

```
11:06:25.247272 IP 10.0.1.3.50953 > 10.0.1.1.domain: 7088+ A? www.kernel.org. (32)
11:06:25.282723 IP 10.0.1.1.domain > 10.0.1.3.50953: 7088 3/0/0 CNAME pub.us.kernel.org., A 149.20.4.69, A 198.145.20.140 (85)
```

or

```
11:06:30.622744 IP 10.0.1.3.62767 > 10.0.1.1.domain: 2439+ A? e3191.c.akamaiedge.net.0.1.cn.akamaiedge.net. (62)
11:06:30.639279 IP 10.0.1.1.domain > 10.0.1.3.62767: 2439 1/0/0 A 184.85.109.15 (78)
```

"A?" means that a query is being done for an A record; "CNAME" means that a CNAME record is being returned (i.e., "www.kernel.org" is an alias for "pub.us.kernel.org", and "A" means that an A record is being returned, giving an IPv4 address.

In Wireshark or TShark, it would look like:

```
12.316361     10.0.1.3 -> 10.0.1.1     DNS Standard query 0xc2fa  A 1.courier-sandbox-push-apple.com.akadns.net
12.332894     10.0.1.1 -> 10.0.1.3     DNS Standard query response 0xc2fa  A 17.149.34.59 A 17.149.34.61 A 17.149.34.62 A 17.149.34.63 A 17.149.34.57
```

or

```
15.163941     10.0.1.3 -> 10.0.1.1     DNS Standard query 0x168c  A www.gnu.org
15.176266     10.0.1.1 -> 10.0.1.3     DNS Standard query response 0x168c  CNAME wildebeest.gnu.org A 208.118.235.148
```

If you're only trying to capture DNS packet, you should use a capture filter such as "port 53" or "port domain", so that non-DNS traffic will be discarded.  That filter will work with Wireshark, TShark, or tcpdump (as they use the same libpcap code for packet capture).